# iOS - How to call a method without initialising the class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

A perfect example of calling a method without initialising the class in Swift is for `UIColor`.

You can do `UIColor.whiteColor()`. Notice how the `()` is at the end of `whiteColor`.

If I were to extend `UIColor` for a custom method:

```
extension UIColor {
    /** Set the color to white. */
    func white() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
}
```

I would have to call this method like so: `UIColor().white()` instead of like this `UIColor.white()`.

How can I write methods where the initialiser is only at the end? Or is this only available when the class is written in Objective-C?

Comment: they've already done that in Swift 3 for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the function either a `class` or `static` function. For example:

```
extension UIColor {
    /** Set the color to white. */
    class func white() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
}
```

You can also use the word `static` instead of class.